# Laravel Complicated inner join on many to many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

A customer belongs to 3 different things:  `rate_schedule_id`, `electricity_code_id`, and 'territory_code_id'.  The electricity code and the territory code determines which `baseline` they use.  The rate schedule affects what rates apply to those baselines.

I have the following tables:

```
 1. customers
    - rate_schedule_id
    - territory_id
    - electricity_code_id

 2. rate_schedules
    - id

 3. utility_rates
    - id
    - rate_schedule_id

 4. baselines
    - id
    - electricity_code_id
    - territory_code_id
    - value
    - rank

 5. utility_rates_baselines
    - id
    - utility_rate_id
    - baseline_id
```

Table 5 defines a many to many relationship between utility_rates and baselines.  The query I am trying to do is:

`Get all baselines that apply given the electricity code, territory code, and rate_schedule sorted by rank.`

Which is this query in mysql:

```
SELECT *
FROM base_lines
INNER JOIN utility_rates_base_lines
ON base_lines.id = utility_rates_base_lines.base_line_id
INNER JOIN utility_rates
ON utility_rates.id = utility_rates_base_lines.utility_rate_id
WHERE base_lines.electricity_code_id = 1 
AND base_lines.territory_code_id = 1 AND utility_rates.rate_schedule_id = 1
ORDER BY base_line.rank;`
```

I can get all baselines for a given electricity code and territory code using scopes that I wrote:

```
BaseLine::ofElectricityCodeId(5)->ofTerritoryCode(3);
```

But then I get all the baselines that apply to rates of a different rate_schedule.

I can also get all of the utility rates for a given rate schedule such as:

```
UtilityRate::ofRateSchedule(2);
```

Then I could iterate over each and get the baselines for the given rate_schedule and electricity code.

I'm also open to a new db design.  How can accomplish my query?

Comment: You can use the same SQL code you posted with Laravel Query Builder, http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#joins. The difference is that you wouldn't write SQL itself, you would call methods, which would make it compatible across DBs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @PedroMoreira said, I was able to just build the query using the query builder.  I spent too much time trying to find a dynamic property to be able to do it, but this is the best solution:

```
DB::table('base_lines')
        ->join('utility_rates_base_lines', 'base_lines.id', '=', 'utility_rates_base_lines.base_line_id')
        ->join('utility_rates', 'utility_rates.id', '=', 'utility_rates_base_lines.utility_rate_id')
        ->where('base_lines.electricity_code_id', '=', $electricityCodeId)
        ->where('base_lines.territory_code_id', '=', $territoryCodeId)
        ->where('utility_rates.rate_schedule_id', '=', $rateScheduleId)
        ->select('base_lines.*')->get();
```